# What is this 10-pin ATX power connector (image) and can I power harddisks off it?

Tags: power-supply

I have a 250W PSU out of a Dell R230 (unfortunately I could not find a spec sheet - but it's a stock psu of a Dell R230).

It has this 10-pin (only 9 pins are populated with contacts!) connector that I haven't seen before:

[image]

Does anyone know this connector and is it possible to split out (4x) 12v Molex connectors to power SATA harddisks off it?

Comment: This is the power connector to the SAS backplane.

Comment: the 4 harddrives are powered off a connector from the mainboard

Comment: Ah now I see. I have the non-swappable disks configuration - in which case the drives are powered off a connector on the mainboard. With a backplane for hotswappable drives, the backplane is powered off this connector. So that should mean I should be able to use it to power SATA 4 SATA drives. Any idea on the pin configuration?

Comment: AFAIK this carries only 12V - your SATA drives would need 12V and 5V. Best use a multimeter, black should be ground and yellow +12V

Comment: so the backplane this connector is intended to has interated voltage converters (as it has to power SATA drives too)

Comment: I don't know about exactly this backplane, but yes: Many do have an integrated converter. One of the reasons is, that many servers can be bought with a 3.5" or a 2.5" backplane and while the former need lots of 12V and a bit of 5V, the latter consume all their power on 5V. It is economical to have the same PSU for both options, so the final conversion is done in the storage subsystem.